# How to delete text string using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have the following code:

```
$('.breadcrumb:contains(",")').hide();
```

It does as expected and hides the entire breadcrumb,
but how would I go about just remove the comma?

==========
EDIT:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>,
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

==========

Thanks for any help

Comment: A sample breadcrumb would be helpful. Could you provide one?

Comment: What exactly does `.breadcrumb` match?  A set of links? A single link? Are the commas in the links or between them?  Can it contain more than one comma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.breadcrumb:contains(",")').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

The `.html()` function accepts a function, [you can see the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/html/). The above code replaces all commas in all `.breadcrumb` elements.  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZG8p/

Comment: I was ready to submit the same thing :P: Edit: Infact not quite, "h" is the current innerHTML, "this" is the DOM element. Do you not mean `return h.replace(/,/g, '');`

Comment: Thank you for your help Nick, unfortunately this removes everything from the breadcrumb div :|

Comment: @Keith - Go to the jsfiddle link in my answer, this works...are you wrapping it inside a `document.ready`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.breadcrumb:contains(",")').html($('.breadcrumb:contains(",")')
    .html().replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.hide()` hides the selected node. You're going to have to get the text from the node (using `.text()`), parse it to pull out the comma, and then re-set the text on the node.

Comment: Alternatively, place spans around the commas and just hide them if you don't want to lose data.

Comment: it is auto generated, this is why is has to dynamically done this way

Answer (score 0):

[You can JavaScript's String replace method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).  However, I'm going to go out on a limb and imagine what happened. You had and an array and then you looped through it to generate your bread crumbs and now you want to get rid of the trailing comma.

The solution to that problem is to use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and use ',' as the separator. This way you only have internal commas.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.breadcrumb:contains(",")').remove();
```

Though this will remove it from the DOM, so make sure you select the correct one.